# Error after upgrading Flutter in the dev channel, getter X isn't defined for the class X

Tags: flutter, upgrade, getter

My Flutter project was working as usual until one day I decided to execute "flutter upgrade" 1 month ago and then every time I execute "flutter run", an error message is shown.

• I tried:

- Change to stable channel.
- Execute "Flutter clean".

• I'm in the dev channel and this is my "flutter doctor":

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.1.0-12.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.19041.867], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

• This is the error message in the console when I open the emulator and then execute "flutter run":

```
C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\my_apps\soto_2021>flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling
software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-0.0.4+3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:126:25: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
          knownFolderID.addressOf, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, pathPtrPtr);
                        ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1067:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'LOGFONT'.
 - 'LOGFONT' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(28).cast<Utf16>();
      ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1112:29: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  LOGFONT get elfLogFont => addressOf.cast<LOGFONT>().ref;
                            ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1114:29: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfFullName => addressOf
                            ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1120:26: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfStyle => addressOf
                         ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1126:27: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfScript => addressOf
                          ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2688:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
 - 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(20).cast<Utf16>().unpackString(128);
      ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2699:11: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
 - 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        ..addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(20).value = 0;
          ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2744:24: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get szName => addressOf
                       ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2837:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value;
      ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2840:5: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value =
    ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2845:28: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      String.fromCharCodes(addressOf.cast<Uint8>().asTypedList(pinLength));
                           ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2853:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(idx).value = pinData[idx];
      ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart:38:31: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final iid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                              ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart:56:33: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final clsid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                                ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/winrt/winrt_helpers.dart:86:40: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final riidCalendar = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:197:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:200:49: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
                                                ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:203:48: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IDesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
                                               ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:58:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:61:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileOpenDialog).addressOf,
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:64:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IFileOpenDialog).addressOf,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:99:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:102:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileSaveDialog).addressOf,
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:105:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IFileSaveDialog).addressOf,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:164:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:167:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_KnownFolderManager).addressOf,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:170:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IKnownFolderManager).addressOf,
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:128:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:131:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_NetworkListManager).addressOf,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:134:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_INetworkListManager).addressOf,
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:82:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:84:68: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final hr = CoCreateInstance(GUID.fromString(CLSID_WbemLocator).addressOf,
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:85:64: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, GUID.fromString(IID_IWbemLocator).addressOf, ptr);
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:63:33: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'Utf8'.
 - 'Utf8' is from 'package:ffi/src/utf8.dart' ('../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String toString() => fromUtf8(addressOf);
                                ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1111:7: Error: Struct 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class ENUMLOGFONTEX extends Struct {
      ^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2835:7: Error: Struct 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO extends Struct {
      ^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2960:7: Error: Struct 'EXCEPINFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class EXCEPINFO extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2966:7: Error: Struct 'PROPERTYKEY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class PROPERTYKEY extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2973:7: Error: Struct 'PROPVARIANT' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class PROPVARIANT extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2978:7: Error: Struct 'SAFEARRAY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class SAFEARRAY extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2985:7: Error: Struct 'CLSID' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class CLSID extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7: Error: Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class STATSTG extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2999:7: Error: Struct 'NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7: Error: Struct 'Utf8' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class Utf8 extends Struct {
      ^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7: Error: Struct 'Utf16' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class Utf16 extends Struct {
      ^
../../../Downloads/Aplicaci%C3%B3n/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Error: Expected type 'T' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();
                                ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\USER\Downloads\Aplicaci�n\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1029

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\USER\Downloads\Aplicaci�n\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 51s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       543.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: try ```flutter create .``` => ```flutter clean``` => ```flutter pub get``` =>```flutter run```

Comment: sorry it did not work :( the same error message is shown

Comment: had you found the solution? I'm stuck on same situation

Comment: I found the solution :) There were outdated dependencies, and to fix it, run "flutter pub upgrade --major-versions". Then I execute "flutter run" as usual and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same error. Just update your dependencies by running `flutter pub upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

i think you should upgrade all your packages to your latest version of null safety if cant do that just downgrade your flutter version to the last one that was working for you there is no prblm running recent old version of flutter